# Role list command send objecct Object instead of roles discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

It sends `[object Object]`. There are no errors in the console.

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle('Availible Roles')
 .setColor('RANDOM')
 .setDescription(roles.array().join(' \n'));
message.channel.send(embed, { split: true });
```

rest of the code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(c => c.name.startsWith('A'))
       
        const arr = roles
            .array()
            .join('\n')
            .match(/.{1,2048}/g);

        for (let chunk of arr) {
            // loop through every element (every 2048 characters)
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Available Roles')
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setDescription(chunk);

            message.channel.send(embed); // wait for the embed to be sent
        }
    },
};
```

const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(c => c.name.startsWith('A'))

Comment: How is the `roles` variable defined? Please show more of your code

Comment: I have added it to the question now

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `{ split: true }`. This option can mess up embeds, as it is meant for regular text messages. If you remove it, the embed should work perfectly.

[image: PoC]

---

If you are worried about there being too many roles, and exceeding the 2048 character limit, you can implement this function:

```js
// array of your description split every 2048 characters
const arr = roles
 .array()
 .join('\n')
 .match(/.{1,2048}/g);

for (let chunk of arr) {
 // loop through every element (every 2048 characters)
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Available Roles')
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setDescription(chunk);

 await message.channel.send(embed); // wait for the embed to be sent
}
```

Code Snippet Example:

```js
const string = 'Hello world! This is a string. Strings are very fun. Fun is also very, by definition, fun!'

// array of your description split every 20 characters
const arr = string.match(/.{1,20}/g);

for (let chunk of arr) {
  // loop through every element (every 20 characters)
  console.log(chunk)
}
```

Comment: It sends each role as its own embed | So it's basically flooding the chat

Comment: Why don't you use [`Discord.Util.splitMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage) instead?

Comment: The problem might be that your not `await`ing the message being sent. Make sure you make your execute function async: `async execute(message, args, client)`